# Assigning custom variable to a google charts method

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a php page that creates google-chart based on a value from XML document.

here's excerpt from the code:
defining XML document

```
<script>    
var xmlDoc;
function loadXML() {
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
 xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
 xmlDoc.async=false;
 xmlDoc.load("fighters_fixed.xml");
} else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
 xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
 xmlDoc.load("fighters_fixed.xml");
}
else {
  alert('Your browser does not support XML DOM');
}
}
</script>
```

Google chart code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var data1 = parseInt(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("age")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

function drawChart() {

 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Fights');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Attendance');
        data.addRows(1);
        data.setValue(0, 0, '2006');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 120);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 400);

var diagram = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('show_chart'));
        diagram.draw(data, {width: 690, height: 500, title: 'Attendance in the span 2006-2010',
                          vAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'green'}}, 
        hAxis: {title: 'Value', titleTextStyle: {color: 'green'}}                         
        });
}
```

Now, to get to the point!
I want to grab a value from an XML node and assign it somehow inside that setValue method.
This is how I get the number value from that particular node, I just can't seem to use it inside setValue method and get it to work on the chart.

```
var data1 = parseInt(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("age")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

doesn't work: `data.setValue(0,1,data1);`

Any help, please?